# why my date is not displayed the value altough the value is changed?

Tags: javascript, html

Why I dont see my date if I change the value ?

```
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<input type="date" value="" class="dt" />

<script>
  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const dateS = document.querySelector('.dt');
    dateS.value = '2022-02-02';
  });
</script>
```

it shows me this:

```
tt.mm.jjjj
```

the value is changed but not displayed

Comment: Assuming you actually define the variable `button` to be a reference to the button somewhere before this script: It works just fine, clicking the button changes the date. (If however you didn't do that, then that's your issue, which you should see in your devtools console too as `button is not defined`, and adding `const button = document.querySelector('.btn')` above would fix it.)

Comment: it works but I only paste a bit line of code, i only want to understand why I get no display the html value , the value is changed but not displayed

Comment: It's displayed as well as you can [see here](https://recordit.co/raypKtQDd3) and [try here](https://jsfiddle.net/o8recxnf/)... I'm not sure what the problem is then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define your button element before using it. `const button = document.querySelector('.btn');`

check the code below.

```html
<button class="btn">Button</button>
<input type="date" value="" class="dt" />

<script>
  const button = document.querySelector('.btn');

  button.addEventListener('click', () => {
    const dateS = document.querySelector('.dt');
    dateS.value = '2022-02-02';
  });
</script>
```